# How to download a large file from Google Cloud Storage using Java with checksum control

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, checksum

I want to download large files from Google Cloud Storage using the google provided Java library [com.google.cloud.storage](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.8.0/apidocs/index.html). I have working code, but I still have one question and one major concern:

My major concern is, when is the file content actually downloaded? During (references to the code below) `storage.get(blobId)`, during `blob.reader()` or during `reader.read(bytes)`? This gets very important when it comes to **how to handle an invalid checksum**, what do I need to do in order to actually trigger that the file is fetched over the network again?

The simpler question is: Is there built in functionality to do md5 (or crc32c) check on the received file in the google library? Maybe I don't need to implement it on my own.

Here is my method trying to download big files from Google Cloud Storage:

```
private static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3;
public Path downloadFile(String storageFileName, String bucketName) throws IOException {
    // In my real code, this is a field populated in the constructor.
    Storage storage = Objects.requireNonNull(StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService());

    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, storageFileName);
    Path outputFile = Paths.get(storageFileName.replaceAll("/", "-"));
    int retryCounter = 1;
    Blob blob;
    boolean checksumOk;
    MessageDigest messageDigest;
    try {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    do {
        LOGGER.debug("Start download file {} from bucket {} to Content Store (try {})", storageFileName, bucketName, retryCounter);
        blob = storage.get(blobId);
        if (null == blob) {
            throw new CloudStorageCommunicationException("Failed to download file after " + retryCounter + " tries.");
        }
        if (Files.exists(outputFile)) {
            Files.delete(outputFile);
        }
        try (ReadChannel reader = blob.reader();
             FileChannel channel = new FileOutputStream(outputFile.toFile(), true).getChannel()) {
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(128 * 1024);
            int bytesRead = reader.read(bytes);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                bytes.flip();
                messageDigest.update(bytes.array(), 0, bytesRead);
                channel.write(bytes);
                bytes.clear();
                bytesRead = reader.read(bytes);
            }
        }
        String checksum = Base64.encodeBase64String(messageDigest.digest());
        checksumOk = checksum.equals(blob.getMd5());
        if (!checksumOk) {
            Files.delete(outputFile);
            messageDigest.reset();
        }
    } while (++retryCounter <= MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES && !checksumOk);
    if (!checksumOk) {
        throw new CloudStorageCommunicationException("Failed to download file after " + MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES + " tries.");
    }
    return outputFile;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google-cloud-java storage library does not validate checksums on its own when reading data beyond normal HTTPS/TCP correctness checking. If it compared the MD5 of the received data to the known MD5, it would need to download the entire file before it could return any results from `read()`, which for very large files would be infeasible.

What you're doing is a good idea if you need the additional protection of comparing MD5s. If this is a one-off task, you could use the `gsutil` command-line tool, which does this same sort of additional check.

Comment: Makes sense! If I detect an invalid checksum, is there a way to force the com.google.cloud.storage library to download the file again and not fetch it from a cache?

Comment: I wouldn't bother. If you do get an invalid checksum, the error was very likely to be a network issue, and it won't happen the second time. Also, HTTPS reads made with credentials are almost certainly not gonna be cached unless you're behind a particularly weird corporate firewall. Nonetheless, you could certainly skip most caches by just adding an extra nonsense URL parameter, like "&skipCaching=12345".

Comment: The issue is not the HTTP cache, but the cache in the Java library provided by google (link in the question above). JavaDoc for ReadChannel states that "Implementations of this class may buffer data internally to reduce remote calls." Here is a page that talks about checksum validation, but not answering my question as far as I can see: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags So I'm not working with URL's directly unfortunately.

Comment: I'm still puzzled about how to clear the JAVA-cache _in the ReadChannel class from the google provided Java library_. The documentation states that there is a cache, "Implementations of this class may buffer data internally to reduce remote calls."- How to empty that cache and enforce a new download over the network?

Comment: Sorry, the documentation is a bit confusing. The documentation is suggesting that the first call to ReadChannel.read() may result in the class asking the server for significantly more data than has been requested and holding onto it so that further calls to read() do not require separate RPC calls to the server. A new instance of ReadChannel create from blob.reader() should not make use of that same buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As the JavaDoc of `ReadChannel` says:

> Implementations of this class may buffer data internally to reduce remote calls.

So the implementation you get from `blob.reader()` could cache the whole file, some bytes or nothing and just fetch byte for byte when you call `read()`. You will never know and you shouldn't care.

As only `read()` throws an `IOException` and the other methods you used do not, I'd say that only calling `read()` will actually download stuff. You can also see this in [the sources](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/0a5a27f067ee4b649148ea90974b6536a7f5b671/google-cloud-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/BlobReadChannel.java#L121-L164) of the lib.

Btw. despite the example in the JavaDocs of the library, you should check for `>= 0`, not `> 0`. `0` just means nothing was read, not that end of stream is reached. End of stream is signaled by returning `-1`.

For retrying after a failed checksum check, get a new reader from the blob. If something caches the downloaded data, then the reader itself. So if you get a new reader from the blob, the file will be redownloaded from remote.

Comment: Yes, I've read the JavaDoc. Like you mention, it doesn't help much. Since this is not an answer, just a statement that you are as clueless as I am, I will down vote this. Also the byte check should be alright. The check is according to the JavaDoc och the Blob::reader, so I assume that the channel is in blocking mode.

Comment: I'm not as clueless as you. As I said, the read method will do the network reading. You can see this from the thrown `IOException`. Getting downvotes on a perfectly valid answer does not encourage people to giving you any further answers at all. And finding an erroneous example doesn't mean you have to repeat the error in your own code. Return code of `0` simply does not mean that end-of-stream is reached, that is a fact that no ill-written example can change.

Comment: I'm just reading JavaDoc to ReadableByteChannel, "It is guaranteed, however, that if a channel is in blocking mode and there is at least one byte remaining in the buffer then this method will block until at least one byte is read."

Comment: Sure, but neither its sub-interface `ReadChannel` defines that the channel is in blocking mode, nor does `Blob.reader()` defines that the returned channel is in blocking mode. So depending on this information is called tight coupling, as you depend on an impementation detail that is not part of the publicly documented API.

Comment: I really don't see why you still refuse to take back your faulty down-vote and accept my answer, even after adding a sources link.

Comment: The question, "how to handle an invalid checksum" remains un-aswered. Like you wrote, the downloaded file may be cached so a new call to read() may not help at all.